# Projection-valued measure property

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading the book functional analysis from Dirk Werner.

In this book he introduces a Projection-valued measure (PVM) as follows.

> Let $L(H)$ denote the set of linear,bounded operators $T:H\to H$ on a
>   Hilbertspace $H$. Denote with $\Sigma$ the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on
>   $\mathbb{R}$. A map $$ E : \Sigma \to L(H)$$ is called PVM if all
>   $E(A)$ are orthognal projections with $$ E(\emptyset) =0, \quad E(\mathbb{R})= Id $$
>    and for pairwise disjoint $A_1,A_2,\dots \in
>  \Sigma$ it holds $$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty E(A_i) (x) = E(\cup A_i)(x)
>  \quad \forall x \in H .$$

Now the author claims that is very easy to show that $$E(A) E(B) = E(B)E(A) = E(A\cap B)$$
holds, but he does not give a hint. Why is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then
$$
               E(A\cup B)= E(A)+E(B)
$$
$P^{2}=P$ for an orthogonal projection $P$. Equating the square of the right side with itself leads to $E(A)E(B)+E(B)E(A)=0$, or $E(A)E(B)=-E(B)E(A)$. Then use $E(B)^{2}=E(B)$ and apply this identity twice to conclude that $E(A)E(B)=0$ if $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Now, for general $A$ and $B$:
$$
       E(A)E(B)=\{ E(A\setminus B)+E(A\cap B)\}\{E(B\setminus A)+E(A\cap B)\} \\
         = E(A\cap B)^{2}=E(A\cap B).
$$

Comment: Could you explain how to conclude $E(A)E(B)=0$? I see that $$E(A)E(B)E(A)=0=E(B)E(A)E(B)$$ but I dont see how this helps to get $E(A)E(B)=0$.

Comment: Assume $A\cap B=\emptyset$. I assume you see $E(A)E(B)=-E(B)E(A)$ because $(E(A)+E(B))^{2}=E(A)+E(B)$. Then $E(A)E(B)=E(A)E(B)E(B)=-E(B)E(A)E(B)=E(B)E(B)E(A)=E(B)E(A)$ gives $E(A)E(B)=-E(B)E(A)$ and $E(A)E(B)=E(B)E(A)$ which makes these expressions $0$. In that last equation there are lots of disjoint sets. For example, $(A\setminus B)\cap (A\cap B) =?$, etc.